# how to convert table columns into a table in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I know it's a bad title, but I don't know how to describe my question in a line.
I want to store following information in my database.

```
+----+----------+-----------+-----------+
| id |  name    | cluster_1 | cluster_2 |
+----+----------+-----------+-----------+
|  1 | content_1|       true|     false |
|  2 | content_2|      false|      true |
|  3 | content_3|       true|      true |
+----+----------+-----------+-----------+
```

cluster_1=true means that the content exists on the cluster_1.

As some clusters may added or deleted, I want to store my cluster information in a new table "clusters", and indicate the relation between contents and clusters with a "content_cluster" table.

```
table contents
+----+----------+
| id |  name    |
+----+----------+
|  1 | content_1|
|  2 | content_2|
|  3 | content_3|
+----+----------+

table clusters
+----+----------+
| id |  name    |
+----+----------+
|  1 | cluster_1|
|  2 | cluster_2|
+----+----------+

table content_cluster
+----------+----------+
|content_id|cluster_id|
+----------+----------+
|        1 |        1 |
|        2 |        2 |
|        3 |        1 |
|        3 |        2 |
+----------+----------+
```

But, writing in this way, I don't know how to get a content which is on cluster_1 but isn't on cluster_2,  or vice versa. I have to do this query frequently. So what is the efficient way to do this?

Comment: So you want to make a list of clusters with their content information? Cluster 1 -> has content 1 and 2, c. 2 has content 2...

Comment: I'm sorry. I haven't described the question well. I want to replace the old table with three new table, which are "contents", "clusters" and "content_cluster". I don't know how to write select function to get one content which is on cluster_1 but not on cluster_2 effectively. Or should I dispose the new design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to get a content which is on cluster_1 but isn't on cluster_2

in general

```sql
SELECT contents.name
FROM contents
JOIN content_cluster ON contents.id = content_cluster.content_id
LEFT JOIN clusters ON clusters.id = content_cluster.cluster_id
GROUP BY contents.name
HAVING  SUM(clusters.name = 'cluster_1') -- not zero, may add ">0"
   AND !SUM(clusters.name = 'cluster_2') -- zero, may replace NOT ("!") with "=0"
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
-- For cluster 1
INSERT INTO new_table (content_id, cluster_id)
SELECT old_table.content_id, 1
FROM old_table
WHERE old_table.cluster_1 = TRUE; 

-- For cluster 2
INSERT INTO new_table (content_id, cluster_id)
SELECT old_table.content_id, 2
FROM old_table
WHERE old_table.cluster_2 = TRUE;
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I haven't described the question well. I want to replace the old table with three new tables for extensibility. But I don't know how to  write my select function to get one content which is on cluster_1 but not on cluster_2 efficiently.